# How ContentFlow scales the images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms, dragonfly-gem

Have been using ContentFlow as a JS image gallery.

I have only one version of image files sized to 1000x750 landscapes and 600x800 portraits and none exceeds 300kb.

i have set `maxItemSize:400;`

When I first load the page, the images show scaled over 100% around 115%. If I reload the page they get back to normal "whatever"x400

If you are curious: http://severe-sky-414.herokuapp.com/

Thanks...